# debug assertion failed! (c++)

Tags: c++, debugging, error-handling, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to create a program that analyzes an inputted word to see if it is a palindrome or not.

I'm doing this bit by bit, and this is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(string word) {
cout << "Word: ";
cin >> word;
bool x = true;
int length = word.length();
int k = length;
    int y = 0;
    for (int i = length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int j = k - 1;
            int l = i - j;
            char a = word[i];
            char b = word[l];
            cout << "a: " << a << "     b: " << b << endl;
            k = k - 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It produces the output I want:

```
Word: marcus
a: s       b: m
a: u       b: a
a: c       b: r
a: r       b: c
a: a       b: u
a: m       b: s
```

But every time I run it, it gives me this error:

> Debug Assertion Failed! Line: 106
>
> Expression: "(_Ptr_user & (_BIG_ALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT - 1))) == 0" && 0

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [_`int main(string word) {`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ff8b6d038e27ce6)_ Huh?? Fixing the warnings first would be a very good idea.

Comment: It will be a separate function in the final program, and it didn't given me a warning about this.

Comment: Oh!! That fixed it!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *`cin >> word;`*

In combination with the invalid parameter signature for `main()`:

```
int main(string word) {
      // ^^^^^^
```

screws up the call stack for the `main()` function from the OS dependent binding code.

That's why you're getting a debug assertion error.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, `main` does not come with an argument of type `string`. Make that a declaration inside the body of the function:

```
int main() {
    std::string word;
```

And some advice: that code is quite confusing! The goal is to loop through the input string and show corresponding characters, so just do that. For a character at position `i`, the corresponding index from the back of the string is `word.length() - 1 - i`. Start out by just writing it that way and be sure that it works. Then maybe store `word.length()` in a separate variable. Beyond that, more variables just makes it harder to see what's going on, and doesn't make the code any better.